# Why IAP product count is empty?

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase

I added three inapp purchases to the app and they have "Ready to submit" status.

Can I test them before submitting the application on the simulator?

I'm asking it because

```
response.products
```

are empty, when I'm using this method.

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        if response.products.count != 0 {
            for product in response.products {
                print(product.localizedTitle)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have the "Paid Applications Agreement" signed in App Store Connect before you can test products.

Also, the simulator is always sketchy for testing anything with `StoreKit` and I recommend testing on a physical device.